# how to add google map in a page using php,jquery

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter-2

Im working on a project..I have to add a google map of my location.Im new to this so any help will be appreciated . I know there are many tutorial but i cant find the best one.Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

you might want to start [here](http://maps.google.com/help/maps/getmaps/plot-one.html). This a tutorial from Google.

Comment: hey thanks finally i got my google map on my site :) it was easy thanks @sikas

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps API is very powerful but you need to have detailed information about Javascript (Jquery), PHP, mySql etc. Also you have to be familiar with Google Map services.

If you do not have enough time for that, you can have a look this PHP [script](http://googlemap.webmountain.net/php/index.php). It is FREE and you can easily embed google maps on your PHP website. Also, it's possible to manage your maps without coding.